# Split data by empty row and rename the new sheets by cell value from the original data set

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following data set in `Sheet1` with headings as you see below:
[image]

I want to split the big data set into different sheets by every **empty row**. Every data set is separated by an empty row, and every data set have values in all cells in columns **A** and **E** but their columns **B**, **C**, **D** might have some empty cells randomly. So the defining element to split is the empty rows in column **E**. 

**Q1:** I want to copy the headings **A1:D1** to the new sheets and **only** copy the columns **A:D** and not the column **E**. 

**Q2:** I want to rename new sheets to take the cell value in column **E** as their name.

So the ***results** are the following:
Sheet `ID1`:
[image]

Sheet `ID2`:
[image]

Sheet `ID3`:
[image]

I have tried the following code, it works, but it only copies the first table, without renaming the sheet to take the cell value in column E, and it should copy the column **E** so it should copy only **A:D**, and it doesn't loop through all tables.

```
Sub Split_Sheets_by_row()
    Dim lLoop As Long, lLoopStop As Long
    Dim rMove As Range, wsNew As Worksheet

    Set rMove = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A:E")
    lLoopStop = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rMove, "Heading5")
    For lLoop = 1 To lLoopStop
        Set wsNew = Sheets.Add
        rMove.Find("Heading5", rMove.Cells(1, 1), xlValues, _
        xlPart, , xlNext, False).CurrentRegion.Copy _
        Destination:=wsNew.Cells(1, 1)
    Next lLoop
End Sub
```

**Your help is very much appreciated.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've taken a slightly different approach but I have achieved the results you are looking for.

```
Sub Split_Sheets_by_row()
    Dim hdr As Range, rng As Range, ws As Worksheet, wsn As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Long, lr As Long, b As Long, blks As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        Set hdr = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 4)
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
        rw = 2
        blks = Application.CountBlank(.Range(.Cells(rw, 1), .Cells(lr, 1))) + 1
        For b = 1 To blks
            Set rng = .Cells(rw, 1).CurrentRegion
            Set rng = rng.Offset(-CBool(b = 1), 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count + CBool(b = 1), 4)
            Set wsn = Worksheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
            With wsn
                .Name = rng.Offset(0, 4).Cells(1, 1).Value
                hdr.Copy Destination:=.Cells(1, 1)
                rng.Copy Destination:=.Cells(2, 1)
            End With
            rw = rw + rng.Rows.Count + 1
            Set rng = Nothing
            Set wsn = Nothing
            If rw > lr Then Exit For
        Next b
    End With
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

The header is stored for repeated use and the number of blocks of data are counted by counting the separating blank rows and adding *1*. The value from column E is used to rename the worksheet but is not carried across in the data transfer to the new worksheet.

I'm not sure how you would want to handle a worksheet with the same name already existing but they could be deleted before a new worksheet is renamed.

Comment: thanks. Actually there is a misunderstanding. I want the sheetnames to be renamed after the cell value of their respective data set in the **Sheet1** in column **E**. But your code renames them as **Data 1** and so forth. The cell values in column **E** are unique for each data set and no other sheet in the workbook contains such a sheet with that name. The cell values in column **E** are just **for the sake of this example**, The original data in column **E** are very random value that do not look like each other from one data set to another.

Comment: @Mpondomise - I've made some modification to use column E for the name of the new worksheet but not to carry column E across in the data transfer.